# Excel VBA - downloading multiple historical exchange rates

Tags: excel, currency, vba

I've been trying to create a table that automatically provides a range of exchange rates for a given period that is specified by the user. I came across [this article](http://investexcel.net/222/automatically-download-historical-forex-data-into-excel/) which I found very useful, and I've been trying to expand the VBA code to include multiple currency conversions. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this and am stuck with following error:

> Error 1004: Microsoft Office Excel can convert only one column at a
>   time. The range can be many rows tall but no more than one column
>   wide. Try again by selecting cells in one column only.

Could you please have a look at my code below and help me resolve the error so that I can obtain multiple currency conversions? Many thanks in advance.

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim endDate As String
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Sheets("GBP").Cells.Clear

    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

    startDate = DataSheet.Range("startDate").Value
    endDate = DataSheet.Range("endDate").Value

    ' GBP/EUR

    str = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download?quote_currency=" _
    & "GBP" _
    & "&end_date=" _
    & Year(endDate) & "-" & Month(endDate) & "-" & Day(endDate) _
    & "&start_date=" _
    & Year(startDate) & "-" & Month(startDate) & "-" & Day(startDate) _
    & "&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=c&price=bid&view=table&base_currency_0=" _
    & "EUR" _
    & "&base_currency_1=&base_currency_2=&base_currency_3=&base_currency_4=&download=csv"

    With Sheets("GBP").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & str, Destination:=Sheets("GBP").Range("A1"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    Sheets("GBP").Range("A5").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("GBP").Range("A5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=True, OtherChar:=",", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)

    Sheets("GBP").Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 12
    Sheets("GBP").Range("A1:B2").Clear

    LastRow = Sheets("GBP").UsedRange.Row - 6 + Sheets("GBP").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets("GBP").Range("A" & LastRow + 2 & ":B" & LastRow + 5).Clear


    ' GBP/USD

    str = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download?quote_currency=" _
    & "GBP" _
    & "&end_date=" _
    & Year(endDate) & "-" & Month(endDate) & "-" & Day(endDate) _
    & "&start_date=" _
    & Year(startDate) & "-" & Month(startDate) & "-" & Day(startDate) _
    & "&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=c&price=bid&view=table&base_currency_0=" _
    & "USD" _
    & "&base_currency_1=&base_currency_2=&base_currency_3=&base_currency_4=&download=csv"

    With Sheets("GBP").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & str, Destination:=Sheets("GBP").Range("C1"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    Sheets("GBP").Range("C5").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("GBP").Range("C5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=True, OtherChar:=",", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)

    Sheets("GBP").Columns("C:D").ColumnWidth = 12
    Sheets("GBP").Range("C1:D2").Clear

    LastRow = Sheets("GBP").UsedRange.Row - 6 + Sheets("GBP").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sheets("GBP").Range("C" & LastRow + 2 & ":D" & LastRow + 5).Clear

End Sub
```

The error occurs at following line:

```
Sheets("GBP").Range("C5").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("GBP").Range("C5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=True, OtherChar:=",", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
```

Comment: Can you please upload the workbook and give a link ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your raw data in columns C & D? If so you may need to organise them differently, either concatenate the two into C with a comma to separate them (as this is the delimiter used here) or put the data in column d in another row in column c. Then you will need to get rid of the:

```
.CurrentRegion
```

after

```
Sheets("GBP").Range("C5")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation in the [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.currentregion%28v=office.11%29.aspx);

> The current region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows
>   and blank columns.

Given your code `Sheets("GBP").Range("C5").CurrentRegion`...

That means find the first blank row above and below `Sheets("GBP").Range("C5")`. Then find the first blank column to the left and to the right of `Sheets("GBP").Range("C5")`. Everything inside those blank rows and columns becomes your `CurrentRegion`. If this is more than one column, you'll get the error you are getting.

To fix that, you'll need to make sure that area of cells inside the blank rows and columns is only one column.